# Ltr for Persian locale in android

Tags: android, locale

I am developing an app which supports two languages: English("en") and Persian("fa"). I have set `android:supportsRtl="false"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` since I need everything to be from left to right. I set margins for all views that I have but for the ones containing a string, it is not working right and it still seems like it is setting the directions from right to left. How can I fix that? I also tried changing the `layoutDirection` manually to left to right but that did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must handle your locale in all activities. Android by default uses the locale of the device to select the appropriate language dependent resources. 

Also you must consider project minimum sdk. I recommended to you change it to 16 or higher: `minSdkVersion 16`

  
Maybe this [link](http://gunhansancar.com/change-language-programmatically-in-android/) help you.

> I set margins for all views that I have but for the ones containing a string, it is not working right

For this for example you must use from `android:layout_marginEnd` instead of `android:layout_marginRight`. Also in default create your layout for `en` locale and then handle and change it by app locale to `fa` or another locale.

Comment: What do you mean by handling locale in all activities?

Comment: @Athena you must override `attachBaseContext` in your base activity or that activity you want change its locale. Please see linked example in answer.

Comment: @Athena in `en` locale: "YW", in `fa` locale: "خواهش میکنم"  :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use instead of the **right** from the **end** and instead of the **left** from the **start**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="تست"
    android:gravity="start"/>
```

Comment: your min sdk +17? because RTL support after 16

Comment: Yes it is 17 and I am currently testing app on api 23

Comment: change android:supportsRtl="true" and in layout use   android:layoutDirection="ltr" , check this

Comment: Still the same :(

Comment: past your xml for checking